# Why did Rick try to kill another Rick?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In Rick & Morty S3E1, a portal opens up and

> a bomb falls down and blows up Beth & Rick's wife.

Why did the other Rick

> want to kill Rick? Just because he turned away from science

doesn't seem like a reason Rick would kill another Rick.

Comment: Tag for spoilers is `>!` - start a new line and put everything you want to conceal after it. Also try to despoil your title, and remove the [spoiler] notice (I'd do it myself, but I have no idea what to hide since I haven't watched this show). I've left an example of usage, [edit] as needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Later in the same episode, Rick reveals that he had manufactured the tragic backstory to trick the bugs into entering a code that allowed him to hack their Network security.

During the story, Rick is acting as an unreliable narrator so there is not enough information about Rick's past to determine how much of his story was actually true.

To address the question, later in the episode, we are shown Seal Team Rick attempt to assassinate Rick, so it isn't like Ricks don't kill Ricks though at that point Rick is a wanted terrorist, not a no-name Rick.

Comment: I thought he just manufactured the 3 line formula, not the story?

Comment: @Chloe -- we can't tell what Rick made up or not. Except for the Sechuan sauce, which we know existed. And was delicious.

Comment: I think it's also important that even in this fake backstory, Rick didn't try to kill _Rick_.  He said "we'll see about that" and then seemingly dropped the bomb to kill Rick's _wife and daughter_.  His _intention_ seems to be to encourage Rick towards interdimensional travel, thus the line "I didn't make the leap, _I_ did." implying that it was not a personal choice to invent that, but forced on him by other Ricks.

Comment: @Kosmos You wrote “Nick” at one point. Can’t edit due to the “6 characters” rule.

Comment: @Chloe Rick specifically calls it a “*totally* fabricated origin story”. Justin Roiland reinforces that retelling as unreliable, to keep Rick’s backstory a mystery. Dan Harmon even goes so far as to say such an origin story would remove appeal from the character. https://youtu.be/RecdrgB-Odc?t=20s

Comment: @user137369 Thanks!  I have corrected it.

Comment: @Chloe: Logically, there must be more lies than just the three lines, because Beth gets blown up in the backstory. (Even though fan theories exist about Rick being from another dimension altogether, the show was not trying to confirm this fan theory during S03E01)